# ¿Como obtener el valor de una propiedad css con Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy tratando de cambiar el color de una etiqueta  cuando le di click al checkBox, pero al momento de deseleccionar el checkBox quiero que vuelva a su color de fondo normal, para eso uso este script:

```
$(document).on('change', '.chk-seleccion', function () {

        var color_temporal = $(this).parent().css("background");

        console.log(color_temporal);

        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $(this).parent().parent().css("background","#FFE0B2");
        }
        else {
            $(this).parent().parent().css("background", color_temporal);
        }
    });
```

Pero SOLO lo coloca de un mismo color, no sé si hay otro modo de obtenerlo.

```js
$(document).on('change', '.chk-seleccion', function () {

            var color_temporal = $(this).parent().css("background");

            console.log(color_temporal);

            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                $(this).parent().parent().css("background","#FFE0B2");
            }
            else {
                $(this).parent().parent().css("background", color_temporal);
            }
        });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <tbody><tr class="tr-head-interesado">
        <th class=""></th>
        <th>
            DNI:
        </th>
        <th>
            Apellido Paterno:
        </th>
        <th>
            Apellido Materno:
        </th>
        <th>
            Nombres:
        </th>
        <th class="th-asistencia">
            Asistencia:
        </th>
    </tr>

    <tr class="tr-interesado">
        <td class="td-seleccion">
            <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="dni_Inter">78547532</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apePat_Inter">SAHUINCO</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apeMat_Inter">VARGAS</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="nombres_Inter">ALIDA JOAQUINA</label>
        </td>
        <td class="td-asistencia">
            <label>FALTO</label>
            <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
            <label>ASISTIO</label>
            <label class="asistencia_Inter">FALTO</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-interesado">
        <td class="td-seleccion">
            <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="dni_Inter">76544435</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apePat_Inter">YOVERA</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apeMat_Inter">INFANTE</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="nombres_Inter">JUAN MARCOS</label>
        </td>
        <td class="td-asistencia">
            <label>FALTO</label>
            <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
            <label>ASISTIO</label>
            <label class="asistencia_Inter">FALTO</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-interesado">
        <td class="td-seleccion">
            <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="dni_Inter">76474540</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apePat_Inter">PAREDES</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apeMat_Inter">MENDOZA</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="nombres_Inter">JULIO RONAL</label>
        </td>
        <td class="td-asistencia">
            <label>FALTO</label>
            <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
            <label>ASISTIO</label>
            <label class="asistencia_Inter">FALTO</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-interesado">
        <td class="td-seleccion">
            <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="dni_Inter">76475090</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apePat_Inter">RAMOS</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apeMat_Inter">HUANCA</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="nombres_Inter">CLINDIO</label>
        </td>
        <td class="td-asistencia">
            <label>FALTO</label>
            <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
            <label>ASISTIO</label>
            <label class="asistencia_Inter">FALTO</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-interesado">
        <td class="td-seleccion">
            <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="dni_Inter">72766321</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apePat_Inter">MARCELO</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apeMat_Inter">ATOCHE</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="nombres_Inter">JADIRA JAZMIN</label>
        </td>
        <td class="td-asistencia">
            <label>FALTO</label>
            <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
            <label>ASISTIO</label>
            <label class="asistencia_Inter">ASISTIO</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-interesado">
        <td class="td-seleccion">
            <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="dni_Inter">75454576</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apePat_Inter">ACHA</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apeMat_Inter">CASTILLO</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="nombres_Inter">GIANNINA NICOLE</label>
        </td>
        <td class="td-asistencia">
            <label>FALTO</label>
            <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
            <label>ASISTIO</label>
            <label class="asistencia_Inter">FALTO</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-interesado">
        <td class="td-seleccion">
            <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="dni_Inter">75943583</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apePat_Inter">ARHUIS</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apeMat_Inter">CANALES</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="nombres_Inter">NATHALY ANTHUANED</label>
        </td>
        <td class="td-asistencia">
            <label>FALTO</label>
            <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
            <label>ASISTIO</label>
            <label class="asistencia_Inter">ASISTIO</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-interesado">
        <td class="td-seleccion">
            <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="dni_Inter">75435908</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apePat_Inter">REYES</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apeMat_Inter">ANICETO</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="nombres_Inter">GERSON CHRISTIAN</label>
        </td>
        <td class="td-asistencia">
            <label>FALTO</label>
            <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
            <label>ASISTIO</label>
            <label class="asistencia_Inter">FALTO</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-interesado">
        <td class="td-seleccion">
            <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="dni_Inter">74547658</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apePat_Inter">CALLE</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apeMat_Inter">CALLE</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="nombres_Inter">ELVIS MANUEL</label>
        </td>
        <td class="td-asistencia">
            <label>FALTO</label>
            <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
            <label>ASISTIO</label>
            <label class="asistencia_Inter">ASISTIO</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-interesado">
        <td class="td-seleccion">
            <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="dni_Inter">76565446</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apePat_Inter">ZAPANA</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apeMat_Inter">DIAZ</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="nombres_Inter">RAY CARLOS</label>
        </td>
        <td class="td-asistencia">
            <label>FALTO</label>
            <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
            <label>ASISTIO</label>
            <label class="asistencia_Inter">FALTO</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-interesado">
        <td class="td-seleccion">
            <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="dni_Inter">76543354</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apePat_Inter">MANAYAY</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apeMat_Inter">SANCHEZ</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="nombres_Inter">FERNANDO ALONSO</label>
        </td>
        <td class="td-asistencia">
            <label>FALTO</label>
            <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
            <label>ASISTIO</label>
            <label class="asistencia_Inter">ASISTIO</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-interesado">
        <td class="td-seleccion">
            <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="dni_Inter">76475156</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apePat_Inter">POMA</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apeMat_Inter">VIDAL</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="nombres_Inter">GIAN FRANCO ALEXIS</label>
        </td>
        <td class="td-asistencia">
            <label>FALTO</label>
            <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
            <label>ASISTIO</label>
            <label class="asistencia_Inter">FALTO</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-interesado">
        <td class="td-seleccion">
            <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="dni_Inter">74536546</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apePat_Inter">ROJAS</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apeMat_Inter">CONDORI</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="nombres_Inter">MICHAEL DANIEL</label>
        </td>
        <td class="td-asistencia">
            <label>FALTO</label>
            <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
            <label>ASISTIO</label>
            <label class="asistencia_Inter">ASISTIO</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-interesado">
        <td class="td-seleccion">
            <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="dni_Inter">71324657</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apePat_Inter">SAMANIEGO</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apeMat_Inter">AQUINO</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="nombres_Inter">VLADIMIR ILICH</label>
        </td>
        <td class="td-asistencia">
            <label>FALTO</label>
            <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
            <label>ASISTIO</label>
            <label class="asistencia_Inter">FALTO</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-interesado">
        <td class="td-seleccion">
            <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="dni_Inter">45654663</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apePat_Inter">ALIAGA</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apeMat_Inter">GUZMAN</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="nombres_Inter">CARELIA</label>
        </td>
        <td class="td-asistencia">
            <label>FALTO</label>
            <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
            <label>ASISTIO</label>
            <label class="asistencia_Inter">ASISTIO</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-interesado">
        <td class="td-seleccion">
            <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="dni_Inter">74567564</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apePat_Inter">FLORENTINO</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apeMat_Inter">VASQUEZ</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="nombres_Inter">RENE</label>
        </td>
        <td class="td-asistencia">
            <label>FALTO</label>
            <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
            <label>ASISTIO</label>
            <label class="asistencia_Inter">FALTO</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-interesado">
        <td class="td-seleccion">
            <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="dni_Inter">76446650</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apePat_Inter">CARLOS</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apeMat_Inter">CESPEDES</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="nombres_Inter">GLADIS EDITA</label>
        </td>
        <td class="td-asistencia">
            <label>FALTO</label>
            <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
            <label>ASISTIO</label>
            <label class="asistencia_Inter">ASISTIO</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-interesado">
        <td class="td-seleccion">
            <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="dni_Inter">77676575</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apePat_Inter">MARCOS</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apeMat_Inter">HERRERA</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="nombres_Inter">FATIMA CELESTE</label>
        </td>
        <td class="td-asistencia">
            <label>FALTO</label>
            <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
            <label>ASISTIO</label>
            <label class="asistencia_Inter">FALTO</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-interesado">
        <td class="td-seleccion">
            <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="dni_Inter">75435354</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apePat_Inter">HUINCHO</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apeMat_Inter">TAIPE</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="nombres_Inter">ESTEFANI PATRICIA</label>
        </td>
        <td class="td-asistencia">
            <label>FALTO</label>
            <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
            <label>ASISTIO</label>
            <label class="asistencia_Inter">ASISTIO</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-interesado">
        <td class="td-seleccion">
            <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="dni_Inter">76545433</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apePat_Inter">ESPEZA</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apeMat_Inter">GOMEZ</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="nombres_Inter">LIZ MARLENY</label>
        </td>
        <td class="td-asistencia">
            <label>FALTO</label>
            <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
            <label>ASISTIO</label>
            <label class="asistencia_Inter">FALTO</label>
        </td>
    </tr>

</tbody></table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para esto no necesitas saber el valor de la propiedad CSS del elemento, lo que quieres es que vuelva a su posición original sin importar cuál sea.

Una manera sencilla de hacerlo sería especificando un valor cuando el checkbox esté marcado (como ya estás haciendo), y cuando no esté marcado, simplemente quita el atributo que especificaste (asignándole un valor vacío).

De ese modo no tienes que estar controlando el color del padre (o del padre del padre) y toma el valor que tenía por defecto en las hojas de estilo (porque se quita el estilo en línea).

Aquí lo puedes ver funcionando:

```js
$(document).on('change', '.chk-seleccion', function() {

  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $(this).parent().parent().css("background-color", "#FFE0B2");
  } else {
    $(this).parent().parent().css("background-color", "");
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="tr-head-interesado">
      <th class=""></th>
      <th>
        DNI:
      </th>
      <th>
        Apellido Paterno:
      </th>
      <th>
        Apellido Materno:
      </th>
      <th>
        Nombres:
      </th>
      <th class="th-asistencia">
        Asistencia:
      </th>
    </tr>

    <tr class="tr-interesado">
      <td class="td-seleccion">
        <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="dni_Inter">78547532</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="apePat_Inter">SAHUINCO</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="apeMat_Inter">VARGAS</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="nombres_Inter">ALIDA JOAQUINA</label>
      </td>
      <td class="td-asistencia">
        <label>FALTO</label>
        <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
        <label>ASISTIO</label>
        <label class="asistencia_Inter">FALTO</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-interesado">
      <td class="td-seleccion">
        <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="dni_Inter">76544435</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="apePat_Inter">YOVERA</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="apeMat_Inter">INFANTE</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="nombres_Inter">JUAN MARCOS</label>
      </td>
      <td class="td-asistencia">
        <label>FALTO</label>
        <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
        <label>ASISTIO</label>
        <label class="asistencia_Inter">FALTO</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-interesado">
      <td class="td-seleccion">
        <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="dni_Inter">76474540</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="apePat_Inter">PAREDES</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="apeMat_Inter">MENDOZA</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="nombres_Inter">JULIO RONAL</label>
      </td>
      <td class="td-asistencia">
        <label>FALTO</label>
        <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
        <label>ASISTIO</label>
        <label class="asistencia_Inter">FALTO</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-interesado">
      <td class="td-seleccion">
        <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="dni_Inter">76475090</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="apePat_Inter">RAMOS</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="apeMat_Inter">HUANCA</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="nombres_Inter">CLINDIO</label>
      </td>
      <td class="td-asistencia">
        <label>FALTO</label>
        <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
        <label>ASISTIO</label>
        <label class="asistencia_Inter">FALTO</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-interesado">
      <td class="td-seleccion">
        <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="dni_Inter">72766321</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="apePat_Inter">MARCELO</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="apeMat_Inter">ATOCHE</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="nombres_Inter">JADIRA JAZMIN</label>
      </td>
      <td class="td-asistencia">
        <label>FALTO</label>
        <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
        <label>ASISTIO</label>
        <label class="asistencia_Inter">ASISTIO</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-interesado">
      <td class="td-seleccion">
        <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="dni_Inter">75454576</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="apePat_Inter">ACHA</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="apeMat_Inter">CASTILLO</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="nombres_Inter">GIANNINA NICOLE</label>
      </td>
      <td class="td-asistencia">
        <label>FALTO</label>
        <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
        <label>ASISTIO</label>
        <label class="asistencia_Inter">FALTO</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-interesado">
      <td class="td-seleccion">
        <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="dni_Inter">75943583</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="apePat_Inter">ARHUIS</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="apeMat_Inter">CANALES</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="nombres_Inter">NATHALY ANTHUANED</label>
      </td>
      <td class="td-asistencia">
        <label>FALTO</label>
        <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
        <label>ASISTIO</label>
        <label class="asistencia_Inter">ASISTIO</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-interesado">
      <td class="td-seleccion">
        <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="dni_Inter">75435908</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="apePat_Inter">REYES</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="apeMat_Inter">ANICETO</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="nombres_Inter">GERSON CHRISTIAN</label>
      </td>
      <td class="td-asistencia">
        <label>FALTO</label>
        <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
        <label>ASISTIO</label>
        <label class="asistencia_Inter">FALTO</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-interesado">
      <td class="td-seleccion">
        <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="dni_Inter">74547658</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="apePat_Inter">CALLE</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="apeMat_Inter">CALLE</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="nombres_Inter">ELVIS MANUEL</label>
      </td>
      <td class="td-asistencia">
        <label>FALTO</label>
        <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
        <label>ASISTIO</label>
        <label class="asistencia_Inter">ASISTIO</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-interesado">
      <td class="td-seleccion">
        <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="dni_Inter">76565446</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="apePat_Inter">ZAPANA</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="apeMat_Inter">DIAZ</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="nombres_Inter">RAY CARLOS</label>
      </td>
      <td class="td-asistencia">
        <label>FALTO</label>
        <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
        <label>ASISTIO</label>
        <label class="asistencia_Inter">FALTO</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-interesado">
      <td class="td-seleccion">
        <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="dni_Inter">76543354</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="apePat_Inter">MANAYAY</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="apeMat_Inter">SANCHEZ</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="nombres_Inter">FERNANDO ALONSO</label>
      </td>
      <td class="td-asistencia">
        <label>FALTO</label>
        <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
        <label>ASISTIO</label>
        <label class="asistencia_Inter">ASISTIO</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-interesado">
      <td class="td-seleccion">
        <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="dni_Inter">76475156</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="apePat_Inter">POMA</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="apeMat_Inter">VIDAL</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="nombres_Inter">GIAN FRANCO ALEXIS</label>
      </td>
      <td class="td-asistencia">
        <label>FALTO</label>
        <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
        <label>ASISTIO</label>
        <label class="asistencia_Inter">FALTO</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-interesado">
      <td class="td-seleccion">
        <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="dni_Inter">74536546</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="apePat_Inter">ROJAS</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="apeMat_Inter">CONDORI</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="nombres_Inter">MICHAEL DANIEL</label>
      </td>
      <td class="td-asistencia">
        <label>FALTO</label>
        <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
        <label>ASISTIO</label>
        <label class="asistencia_Inter">ASISTIO</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-interesado">
      <td class="td-seleccion">
        <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="dni_Inter">71324657</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="apePat_Inter">SAMANIEGO</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="apeMat_Inter">AQUINO</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="nombres_Inter">VLADIMIR ILICH</label>
      </td>
      <td class="td-asistencia">
        <label>FALTO</label>
        <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
        <label>ASISTIO</label>
        <label class="asistencia_Inter">FALTO</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-interesado">
      <td class="td-seleccion">
        <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="dni_Inter">45654663</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="apePat_Inter">ALIAGA</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="apeMat_Inter">GUZMAN</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="nombres_Inter">CARELIA</label>
      </td>
      <td class="td-asistencia">
        <label>FALTO</label>
        <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
        <label>ASISTIO</label>
        <label class="asistencia_Inter">ASISTIO</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-interesado">
      <td class="td-seleccion">
        <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="dni_Inter">74567564</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="apePat_Inter">FLORENTINO</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="apeMat_Inter">VASQUEZ</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="nombres_Inter">RENE</label>
      </td>
      <td class="td-asistencia">
        <label>FALTO</label>
        <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
        <label>ASISTIO</label>
        <label class="asistencia_Inter">FALTO</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-interesado">
      <td class="td-seleccion">
        <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="dni_Inter">76446650</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="apePat_Inter">CARLOS</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="apeMat_Inter">CESPEDES</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="nombres_Inter">GLADIS EDITA</label>
      </td>
      <td class="td-asistencia">
        <label>FALTO</label>
        <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
        <label>ASISTIO</label>
        <label class="asistencia_Inter">ASISTIO</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-interesado">
      <td class="td-seleccion">
        <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="dni_Inter">77676575</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="apePat_Inter">MARCOS</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="apeMat_Inter">HERRERA</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="nombres_Inter">FATIMA CELESTE</label>
      </td>
      <td class="td-asistencia">
        <label>FALTO</label>
        <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
        <label>ASISTIO</label>
        <label class="asistencia_Inter">FALTO</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-interesado">
      <td class="td-seleccion">
        <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="dni_Inter">75435354</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="apePat_Inter">HUINCHO</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="apeMat_Inter">TAIPE</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="nombres_Inter">ESTEFANI PATRICIA</label>
      </td>
      <td class="td-asistencia">
        <label>FALTO</label>
        <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
        <label>ASISTIO</label>
        <label class="asistencia_Inter">ASISTIO</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-interesado">
      <td class="td-seleccion">
        <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="dni_Inter">76545433</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="apePat_Inter">ESPEZA</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="apeMat_Inter">GOMEZ</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="nombres_Inter">LIZ MARLENY</label>
      </td>
      <td class="td-asistencia">
        <label>FALTO</label>
        <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
        <label>ASISTIO</label>
        <label class="asistencia_Inter">FALTO</label>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Gracias pero, por qué pasa esto? No debería quedarse en blanco el fondo si no le das un valor a la propiedad?

Comment: @GianFrancoAlexisPomaVidal si no le das un valor, entonces se considera un valor incorrecto y se va a la siguiente regla que aplique (la que has puesto en el CSS que indica que debe tener un color u otro). Si no tuvieras esa regla en los estilos, entonces iría al valor por defecto del navegador (transparente, que parecería blanco por estar sobre ese fondo.)